# How do I get the customer session at the time an order is placed?

Tags: ruby, shopify, webhooks

Is there any other way to get the session information? Can I manipulate my scripts in such a way that I call some api on the order fulfillment event, as I think it will provide me the session information?

I tweaked add to cart event somehow to do this (hit an api url) as the add to cart form was available in my admin panel. Can this be done to orders also? Where can I find the order success code in the liquid pages in admin? I hope the question is clear.

What I did to my cart event -

```
<script>
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    var url = "http://myapi.com/event=addtocart&";


  $("form[action='/cart/add']").find(':submit').click(function(event){

    var pid = {{product.id}};
    url += "pid=" + pid;
    script.src = url;
    parent.appendChild(script);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

monitoring an add to cart has zero connection to an order. An order does not exist till checkout is completed. All you know before the order is made, is that a customer with a token exists.

Using an App you can poll for new orders as often as you like, no obligation whatsoever to use a webhook.

Comment: I want to get some order parameters and session information of a user at the time he/she places an order? I am having hard luck even to figure this out.